# Android 7+ send crash information

Tags: android

When a crash happened on Android 4 to 6, my apps gave the user the possibility to send the crash information as an e-email to me as developer.

When running my app on Android 7 Nougat via the normal route (handle UncaughtException) the user cannot get the possibility to send the crash information. How can I send the crash information as e-mail for my app running on Android 7?

Comment: You can use Fabric crash analytics or Firebase crash analytics to get the crash Log. There is no need to send email of crash information I guess.

Comment: On 'downvote' - can you please explain why you downvoted this question? When given a good reason, I will remove the question and/or learn from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[Firebase Crash Reporting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/)**

> Crash Reporting creates detailed reports of the errors in your app. Errors are grouped into issues based on having similar stack traces, and triaged by the severity of impact on your users. In addition to automatic reports, you can log custom events to help capture the steps leading up to a crash.

**Key capabilities**

- Monitor fatal and non-fatal errors
- Collect the data you need to diagnose problems
- Email alerts
- Integrate with Analytics and Remote Config
- Free and easy

Comment: Thank you! When clicking the link, I see the message about Craslytics. Should I start using that? The message: Note: Crashlytics will soon become the primary crash reporter for Firebase. If you aren't already using Crash Reporting to report crashes and non-fatal errors in your app, we recommend using Crashlytics.

Answer (score 1):

See the answer of @Nilesh Rathod,  @Sneha Sarkar (thank you!)

The **successor** of "Firebase Crash Reporting" is Crashalytics. 
   So, if you don't started using such a facility, advised is using Crashalytics.
I have installed it for all my apps. Per app you need 5 minutes if you follow the installation instructions ;-)
It is working fine.

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod - if you downvoted, you can add the Crashalytics and I remove my answer. No prob.

Comment: i didn't downvoted if think you ans is correct than its file +1 for u

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated.